# PDF Reader for iPhone

Tags: iphone, pdf

What's the best PDF reader for the iPhone? I'm curious as to why Adobe has not released anything yet?

Comment: Are you looking for editing/annotation/etc. features?

Comment: No, just for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think iPhone can read PDFs as built-in functionality.

All you need is an app which will let you transfer PDFs over in order to view them, or you can e-mail PDFs to yourself and view them from the built-in Mail app.

The app that I have which does this is called "Air Sharing", but I think you can get free alternatives too.

Comment: This is one way to do it. But really, do I need to download the pdf every time?

Comment: No, if you use Air Sharing, you just transfer the PDF to your iPhone once.  Then using the Air Sharing file explorer you can browse to the PDF and view it.

Comment: Air Sharing also remembers your place in the PDFs, which makes it head and shoulders above reading via MobileSafari.

Comment: So what free program is there that will do what "Air Sharing" does?

Comment: Reading the description of the "Files lite" app, it seems to be similar to Air Sharing.

Comment: If you have MobileMe, Apple finally released an iDisk app for the iPhone so you can transfer files that way.

Answer (score 2):

GoodReader supports passwords, large files and advanced reading & scrolling options.

Comment: I second GoodReader - it is the only PDF reader that I have tried that can handler larger PDFS (> 20 mb) without trouble as I believe it only loads a page at a time into memory instead of the whole file.

Comment: I'll take off the answer for now to see more results.

Comment: I'd second GoodReader as well. for very large PDFs ist has been the only solution for me, having tried out different other apps incl. the ones mentioned below (as of 13.09.09)

Answer (score 1):

[Discover](http://www.mappn.com/soft.php?id=1) is a free app similar to Air Sharing. It lets you to transfer files to another iPhone, and allows you to view a lot of different file formats on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

PDFs are built right into the operating system and so any program that is enabled to can show a PDF in a UIWebView (so good examples are applications like Safari or Mail).

Comment: This is obvious. I was looking for something that can open and close pdfs on the filesystem. Rick's answer works.